# Fluent Bit With AWS EKS Cluster And ELK

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I'm new to Fluent Bit and I'd love to get help from you.

I have trying unsuccessfully so far to embed Fluent Bit tool within my AWS EKS cluster and collect service logs includes ingress-nginx on top of AWS ELB.
In addition, I don't want to create a new ElasticSearch/Kibana cluster since I want to use my existing Apache Kafka & ELK stack.

*What has been recently deployed on my Kubernetes cluster*

**Namespace**

```
kubectl create namespace logging
```

**Service Account**

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-service-account.yaml
```

**Role**

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-role.yaml

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-role-binding.yaml
```

**Fluent Bit to Kafka**

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/output/kafka/fluent-bit-configmap.yaml

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/output/kafka/fluent-bit-ds.yaml
```

Even though I have deployed all of this, the logs have not yet reached the ELK's server.
It's important to note that I've only changed the **Brokers** address within this **filefluent-bit-configmap.yaml** file to my Apache Kafka address (Communication between servers exists).

Comment: You didn't mention what's the problem? So how can we help you?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question.